# Characteristics for impartial games with the same nimber?

Tags: combinatorial-game-theory

I am working on a specific impartial game on graphs. It turns out that graphs that are not isomorphic may have the same nimber. My goal is to characterize graphs with the same nimber. I simply wonder if there is any work done on this question in general instead of for specific games?

Comment: Can you describe your game? It's hard to answer without knowing your game.

Comment: In some sense, the "work done on this question in general" is the mex rule/Sprague-Grundy Theorem and the Nim addition rule. Whether your game is closely related to one that's previously been studied would depend a lot on what your game is exactly.

Comment: If it's my move and I'm going to lose then I'm looking at a graph with nimber zero. So as a special case of your question you're going to need to characterise which positions are losing positions. This is typically a hard problem in any reasonably interesting game. So either your game is easy to play or the problem you want to solve about it is very hard, right?